# Chloropleth map

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am trying to create a choropleth language map but my map is coming out as points and I would prefer shades of colour specifying regions that speak the same language instead of points scattered.

Comment: Is your source data points? What platform are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS. Yes the data is in points

Comment: You will have to join the points to polygon features representing the regions or use raster interpolation.

Comment: What polygons/boundaries are you using to define language regions? Are these pre-defined entities you can download as a shapefile (e.g., countries, states) or do they need to be interpolated from your point data as @Dowlers suggests?

Comment: i am using the country shapefile. so i joined the language file to the attribute table of the enumeration areas using the state name which was common to both of them. the enumeration areas are points.

Comment: what are the enumeration areas? Is the language file a point file? If so join it to your country shapefile assuming this is a polygon feature class.

Comment: The enumeration areas are points shapefiles. The join did not work out. I guess it is because the enumeration areas are 3551 while the attribute table of the country shapefile is 774. I joined the language file to the enumeration area point shapefile as they are both 3551 but I am having challenge converting the point shapefile to a polygon as I want a chloropleth  map.

Comment: You could use the Voronoi Polygons tool to create a polygon for each language point.